# Balloon in a container inside a vacuum chamber

Tags: forces, pressure, vacuum, ideal-gas, stress-strain

The question I'm trying to understand is and getting a bit stuck with:

Let's say we put a small balloon filled with air of volume, e.g., $1cm^3$ inside a container. This container is not sealed i.e. it has holes and experiences vacuum. Both containers are then placed inside a vacuum chamber.

The balloon expands, e.g. x$10$, and increases in volume, and fills the container of volume, e.g. $5cm^3$.

If the balloon doesn't have the space to expand i.e. the container is not big enough to allow for the full expansion volume of $10cm^3$;
how can we calculate the pressure exerted by the balloon onto the container from the "failed" expansion?

What I don't quite get is relating the volume expansion to pressure being exerted on the container to then be able to determine if the container will yield.

Is it as simple as the pressure in the balloon after expansion? so the P2 variable from the combined pressure law.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You need to subtract the strain energy gained by the balloon material per unit volume expansion. A balloon's pressure is higher than the external pressure because of the energetic cost of stretching the rubber.

Comment: Re, "Is it as simple as..." There's room for complications. If it's a homework problem, then you probably are allowed to make certain assumptions. Like, the initial pressure in the balloon. Are you allowed to assume that it's the same as atmospheric pressure? Maybe. Initial and final temperatures, are you allowed to assume that they are the same? (If you actually do the experiment, they _won't_ be the same if you don't take steps to control the temperature.)

Comment: Does the combined gas laws not take into account the temperature change? i.e. charles law
The initial pressure of the balloon is assumed to be at atmospheric, my model combines the altitude expansion + the expansion when under negative pressure.
The vacuum chamber would be a temp controlled environment. 

@Chemomechanics I'll investigate that route. Is the external pressure the vacuum or the pressure from the container? So I need to compare the resistance to expansion of the casing to the strain energy from expansion